# Where do the 'Build Variants' in AppCenter come from and is there extra setup required for each one?

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I am struggling to get my AppCenter to build my Android app, so I wanted to try and understand a few things to see if I can debug the issue.

Where do the different build variants come from and what significance are they when choosing, as in what do I need to make sure is set in my gradel files etc in order for them to run correctly?

In my case I have the following available.

[image]

Having a look in my app.iml file, I can see that the 'SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT' is set to `devMinSdkKernelDebug` however I do not see this in any of the build variant listed on AppCenter, so I am wondering if this is the reason the build is failing?

[image]

The error I am getting on AppCenter is that 'assembleDevMinSdkDebug' not found in project ':app'.  Whereas the ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME is set to assembleDevMinSdkDevKernalDebug in the iml file?  I have tried changing these to match but still not working, but thinking I may need to do some extra set up elsewhere?

Please if anyone has any ideas I would like to hear them as I am totally stumped!

[image]

In case it has any relevance, here is my android folder

[image]

Comment: I've the same problem. My problem is that I use flavorDimensions. At the moment App Center does not support multiple flavor dimensions.
Visit [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/issues/32).

Answer (score 0):

From the AppCenter document:

> The available build variants will populate from the Build Types and
>   Product Flavors specified in the build.gradle file. Select which build
>   variant should be built.

[Build variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/first-build#32-build-variant)

So I think you should check your build.gradle file instead of the app.iml file.